# Watchr: Undefined method `watch' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, watchr

I am using watchr to watch and compile my stylus and haml files, but as soon as I run the watchr command, I get an error message saying: `<main>: undefined method watch' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`.
My watchr.rb file looks like this

```
def compile_haml
  %x[haml index.haml ../index.html]
end

def compile_stylus
  %x[stylus style.styl -o ../style.css]
end

watch( "index.haml" ) { |x|
  %x[haml index.haml ../index.html]
}

watch( "style.styl" ) { |x|
  %x[stylus style.styl -o ../style.css]
}
```

How do I fix this problem? Can it be fixed?

Comment: How did you execute this script?

Comment: I used the node.js command line with the command `watchr watchr.rb` @avellable

Answer (score 0):

I think renaming the file to watchr.watchr should fix it.

```
$ watchr watchr.watchr
```